# Python add numbers up in loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list of numbers:

list1 = [33, 11, 42, 53, 12, 67, 74, 34, 78, 10, 23]

What I need to do is calculate the total amount of numbers in the list, then divide by 360 to work out portions of a circle. For this example it would be 32. Which I have done below:

```
def heading():
    for heading_loop in range(len(list1)):
        heading_deg = (360 / len(list1))
    return heading_deg
```

The problem I have is that I need to have the number (heading_deg) append by the last number everytime it runs throught the loop. E.g.

```
run 1:  32
run 2:  64
run 3:  96
run 4:  128
```

etc etc

Any ideas?? At the moment all it does it return 32, 11 times.

Thanks!!

Comment: So the portions of the circle are divided equally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry I've posted another answer but I think what you wanna do is different from what you show in your code. Have a look if this is what you want:

```
def heading():
    result=[] #create a void list
    numbersum=sum(list1) #"calculate the total amount of numbers in the list"
# e.g. if list=[1,1,2] sum(list) return 1+1+2. 
    for i in range(len(list1)):
         result.append(((list1[i])/float(numbersum))*360) # calculate portion of the circle ("then divide by 360 to work out portions of a circle") 
#in this case if you have a list A=[250,250] the function will return two angle of 180° 
    #however you can return portion of the circle in percent e.g. 0.50 is half a circle 1 is the whole circle simply removing "*360" from the code above 
    return result
```

If you try:

```
 test=heading()
 print test
 print sum(test)
```

The last should print 360°.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're looking for cumulative sum:

```
def func(list1):
    tot_sum = 0
    add = 360/len(list1)
    for _ in xrange(len(list1)):
        tot_sum += add
        yield tot_sum

>>> for x in func(list1):
    print x


32
64
96
128
160
192
224
256
288
320
352
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't undersand what you want.
It's normal the same value is returned, you don't use heading_loop.
So, heading_deg = (360 / len(list1)) is aleready the same result.

How you have 32, then 64, then 96 in the iteration ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the portions of the circle are equally distributed.

The problem with your code is that although heading_deg is computed multiple times, it's always computed the same way, since `360/len(list1)` never changes. As Ashiwni points out, you do need a cumulative sum. In case you need to return the cumulative sum as function output, you can use a generator:

```
def heading():
    deg = (360 / len(list1))
    for heading_loop in range(len(list1)):
        yield (heading_loop+1)*deg
```

To use the generator:

```
heading_deg_gen = heading()
print heading_deg_gen.next() # prints 32
print heading_deg_gen.next() # prints 64

# or, you can loop through the values
for heading_deg in heading_deg_gen:
    print heading_deg # prints the rest of the values up to 360
```

Also, by using integer arithmetic, you are losing some precision here. This can be fine and even desired in some cases, but if you'd rather have a more precise answer, use `360.0/len(list1)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just use your loop counter & append the calculate result into a list.

```
list1 = [33, 11, 42, 53, 12, 67, 74, 34, 78, 10, 23]

def heading():
    heading_deg = []
    for heading_loop in range( len( list1 ) ):
        heading_deg.append( ( 360 / len( list1 ) ) * ( heading_loop + 1 ) )
    return heading_deg
```

Return value is:

```
[32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 256, 288, 320, 352]
```